# ¿Como mostrar un modal o un div persistente en php o javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Buenas tardes, no se ni por donde comenzar, tengo un sistema de subasta donde el usuario espera en una pagina ha que llegue un producto enviado desde una aplicación, cuando se muestra el producto al usuario este debe contener un tiempo de caducidad para comprar, lo que necesito es que apenas mi producto se muestre al usuario aparezca un modal o un div donde muestre el tiempo de caducidad de compra pero que este modal o div sea persistente osea que no se desaparezca si el usuario navega en otras pestañas.

Aquí un ejemplo gráfico de lo que necesito. se los agradezco, el lenguaje puede ser php o javascript no hay problema.

Edito: Lo ideal seria que la ventana se pudiera  minimizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Guille, definitvamente podemos ayudarte. Sería bueno que pudieras [edit] tu pregunta y mostraras lo que ya llevas echo para echarte una mano.

Comment: Hola kenny gracias por tu interés pues sinceramente solo necesito saber una forma para que el modal permanezca persistente del resto ya se esta trabajando y no tengo ningun lio, voy a revisar la respuesta de @Briska117 y si me sirve de guia o para implementar publicare mi respuesta ;)

Comment: En PHP utiliza una variable de sesión para saber si debes mostrar o no ese div y en Javascript muestra el tiempo restante para que caduque.